# Docker tag flag not working when building from Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I used the following to create a docker image from a Dockerfile:

```
docker build -t basickarl/sensu-core /srv/dockerfile/sensu/sensu-core
```

However when I check my image file it displays the tag at `<none>`:

```
root@instanty-1:~# docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>                  <none>              c5a2e202f5d5        6 hours ago         294.8 MB
```

I don't really understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happen when an error occurred during the image build

Probably you have an error in your Dockerfile